# Why does my specific JavaScript algorithm, which uses 1 array of size n, always use up more memory than another that uses 3 arrays of size n?

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, memory

I am looking at the LeetCode problem [Product of Array Except Self](https://leetcode.com/problems/product-of-array-except-self/). I have one JS solution that uses a single array of size n (n being the length of the input array), and another that is very similar, but uses 3 arrays of size n. No matter how many times I submit the solutions, the 1-array solution seems to use way more space than the 3-array solution. (I say it uses "way more space" because while the actual difference is only a few MB, the percentile difference is huge - the 1-array solution [uses more space than about 90-95% of submissions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lkbqq.png), while the 3-array solution [uses more space than about 50-60% of submissions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aM9wZ.png).)

I also have a 2-array solution that consistently falls in the middle of my other two solutions in terms of space usage. This makes sense, but the order is reversed - I would expect the 1-array solution to always use less space than the 3-array solution. To make things stranger, I have tested somebody else's 1-array solution, and theirs [uses much less space than my 1-array solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RzOiI.png), but I can't understand why. Perhaps it's a quirk of JS that I'm unaware of, or perhaps I'm missing something obvious. Any input would be much appreciated!

Here are the solutions. The actual algorithmic logic is essentially the same; the main difference is how many arrays they use.

3-array solution (the 3 arrays of size n are left, right, and res):

```
const productExceptSelf = function(nums) {
    const left = [];
    const right = new Array(nums.length);

    for (let i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
        if (i === 0)
            left.push(1);
        else
            left.push( left[i - 1] * nums[i - 1] );
    }
    for (let i = nums.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (i === nums.length - 1)
            right[i] = 1;
        else
            right[i] = right[i + 1] * nums[i + 1];
    }

    const res = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < nums.length; i++)
        res.push( left[i] * right[i] );

    return res;
};
```

1-array solution (it uses the same logic as the above, but uses a single res array of size n):

```
const productExceptSelf = function(nums) {
    const res = [ 1 ];

    for (let i = 1; i < nums.length; i++)
        res.push( res[i - 1] * nums[i - 1] );

    let right = 1;
    for (let i = nums.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        res[i] *= right;
        right *= nums[i];
    }

    return res;
};
```

Someone else's 1-array solution (I understand why it would be faster than mine since it uses just 1 loop, but I don't see why it would use so much less space since the res array is also size n):

```
const productExceptSelf = function(nums) {
    const res = [];
    let leftMult = 1;
    let rightMult = 1;
    
    for (let i = nums.length - 1, j = 0; i >= 0; i--, j++) {
        res[i] = (res[i] ?? 1) * rightMult;
        res[j] = (res[j] ?? 1) * leftMult;
        
        rightMult *= nums[i];
        leftMult *= nums[j];
    }
    
    return res;
}
```

Comment: Instead of pushing values to ```res```, try creating an array of size ```n``` and assign the values to indices? That should speed up your approach

Comment: @AbhinavMathur Thanks for the suggestion! I'm less concerned about the speed, and more just confused about the space usage, but I've noted your advice for the future and will definitely keep it in mind.

Comment: I think push allocates new memory every time used. Maybe it would reduce memory to  allocate the array beforehand (size).